# {2} ⊆ P({2,3}) vs {{2}} ⊆ P({2,3})

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

{2} ⊆ *P*({2,3}) - False

{{2}} ⊆ *P*({2,3})  - True

Why is that the case above?

I've tried analyzing it, and it came to this,

For the 1st statement, they are claiming that {2} is a subset of *P*({2,3}. This is false because for {2} ⊆ *P*({2,3}), every element in {2} must also be in *P*({2,3}).

However, for the 2nd statement, I don't quite get what the double curly brace represent.

Comment: $\{\{2\}\}$ is the set which contains $\{2\}$ as its only member, which is a set. I'm guessing $P$ means powerset. $\{2\}\in P(\{2,3\})$, but isn't a subset of the powerset. For example, $1\in\{1,2\}$, $\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}$ $\{1\}\notin\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @ jdods
Yes *P* means power set.
So {2} represents an element, where as {{2}} is a set?

Comment: Yes, the set $\{2\}$ is the only element contained in the set $\{\{2\}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right thought for why $\{ 2 \}$ is not a subset.

What $\{\{2\}\}$ stands for is the set containing the set $\{2\}$. This can be a little confusing, so think of it as $\{ x \}$ where $x=\{2\}$ (in the first question we have $\{y\}$ where $y=2$: note that $y$ is a number whilst $x$ is a set).

So using the same logic as for the first part of the question, every element in $\{\{2\}\}$  must be an element of $P(\{2,3\})$. So we need to show $\{2\} \in P(\{2,3\})$.

Assuming that $P(\{2,3\})$ stands for the power set of $\{2,3\}$, this means we have to show $\{2\} \subseteq \{2,3\}$. This is the same as showing that $2 \in \{2,3\}$, which is true. Therefore $\{\{2\}\} \subseteq P(\{2,3\})$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $2\in \{2,3\}$, so you must have $\{2\}\in \mathcal{P}(\{2,3\}).$  However, you do not have $\{2\}\in \{2,3\}$, so you do not have $\{\{2\}\}
\in \mathcal{P}(\{2,3\}).$